# Caching when using Query Expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, performance, collections

I was reading an article about how query expressions defer executions. Does that mean when we have a collection like:

```
IEnumerable<int> collection = from i in integers where i % 2 == 0 select i;
```

It is gonna be recalculated every time the `collection` is accessed?

If so, what's the general practice to deal with this? To convert into a new collection?

Also why did the C# designers chose it this way, and not something where it caches the result into the collection after the first access to the collection?

Also how does the runtime know that `collection` behaves this way (defer executions), unlike another `IEnumerable<T>` I might create using a `List<T>` which doesn't defer executions?

---

#### Edit:

What about cases like this:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int> ( ) { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };

var even = from i in ints where i % 2 == 0 select i;

ints.AddRange ( new List<int> ( ) { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 } );

foreach ( int i in even )
{
    Console.WriteLine ( i );
}
```

---

#### Output:

```
2, 4, 6, 8, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50
```

By caching, would the behavior be more expected?

Comment: You're thinking about this completely the wrong way. "even" is not a collection at all. It is a QUERY.  It is an object which represents the query "filter ints so that you only get the even numbers".  That's all it is, just an object which represents that query. Whenever you enumerate it, the query executes.  When you think about it like that, it becomes clear why nothing is cached: the query RESULTS could be different every time, but the QUERY hasn't changed.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I got it now. I didn't think of it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will be recalculated every time.

If you want to cache it, use `ToArray()` on the result (or `ToList()` if you want to add new items later).

The reason why it does not cache it after the first try is because it's fairly tricky to do it right in a thread-safe way. Normally, enumerating a collection is considered a thread-safe operation. However, if the implementation would cache items as they're being enumerated, it would either become non-safe for multiple readers (surprising to users and highly undesirable), or do explicit locking on the cache on every step, which significantly affects performance. And that performance penalty would be there even when you actually don't have several threads reading collection at the same time - locks are inherently expensive.

Another point is that the caching behavior is not very obvious when query expression referenced mutable variables that were changed between the point it was executed, and the point where result is enumerated. When you do eager evaluation, the values are what they were at the query point. When you do non-caching deferred evaluation, the values are always what they are at the enumeration point. With caching, you do not know - it depends on whether it's the first time you enumerate it or not.

Yet another point is that it cannot really know whether caching is needed or not. If you're only going to enumerate the sequence once (which is a very frequent case), then caching items wastes both time and memory.

F# actually has a standard type for such a lazy caching sequence, which is called `LazyList` - you can wrap any `IEnumerable` into that to get the desired semantics, with all the caveats described above.

Comment: Thanks Pavel. In my edit, was this what you mean by your 4th paragraph?

Comment: I'm not sure. Looking at your edit, it seems that by "caching" you actually mean just "caching values when enumeration begins", but rather "fully executing the query at the point it is performed and storing the result". The paragraph you refer to in my reply talks about the former case and not the latter one.

Answer (score 2):

I find it easier to think of an `IEnumerable<T>` as a sequence rather than a collection, which is the terminology F# uses. Fundamentally, all an `IEnumerable` promises is that it can return an `IEnumerator`, which itself provides a simple contract that happens to have a fancy language construct to make it easy to use: `foreach`.

So instead of thinking of LINQ as filtering your collection, think of the methods as returning sequences that will meet your criteria when they are enumerated. When your query is compiled into this...

```
IEnumerable<int> collection = integers.Where(i => i % 2 == 0);
```

...think of `collection` as a sequence of the values in `integers` that are even, rather than a "collection" of such integers. I would even rename `collection` to something more accurate like `evenIntegers`.

To answer your specific questions:

1. it's gonna be recalculated every time the collection is accessed?

   Each call to `collection.GetEnumerator()` will return a new enumerator, yes. In fact, if you enumerate `collection` and then update `integers`, enumerating `collection` again will produce a different result. And calling additional deferred LINQ operators would just return new sequences that operate on the filtered `collection` sequence, again without actually calculating anything until they are enumerated.
2. If so, what's the general practice to deal with this? To convert into a new collection?

   In general, you should defer execution as long as possible. By chaining various LINQ methods, it's possible to build up a really "smart" sequence that won't actually do anything until you use `foreach` (or `First`, `Last`, an aggregation like `Count`, etc).
3. Also why did the C# designers chose it this way, and not something where it caches the result into the collection after the first access to the collection?

   The various immediate operators (ToArray, ToList, ToDictionary, ToLookup) were provided to support scenarios where an in-memory collection is needed. It's easy to cache a deferred sequence; it's impossible to un-defer a cached sequence.
4. Also how does the runtime know that collection behaves this way (defer executions), unlike another IEnumerable I might create using a List which doesn't defer executions?

   As I suggested before, the runtime doesn't really know anything about how a particular `IEnumerable<T>` is going to behave. It just knows that it will provide an enumerator. It's up to the individual implementer (like `List<T>`) to decide how it wants behave.

Comment: For an interesting example of a sequence that's not a "real" collection, check out Continuous LINQ: http://www.codeplex.com/clinq